# How to Write Nested while loop of php in laravel with mysql

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

can anyone tell me how to convert in this pseudo code in laravel? like inner loop sql table condition depend upon the value coming from parent loop.

```
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
{ 
      $query = select * from table where id=$row['id];
       $result2 = mysqli_query($query,$conn);

        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)
         {
             echo $row2['id'];
         }

}
```

any idea?

Comment: Use relationships and subqueries

Comment: Paras how could controller send to the view one by one. i need once this schema like company has some projects and projects have some tasks.
i want to print in the view:
first company
  first project
                 first task
                 second task
  second project
                 first task
                 second task
second company
  first project
                 first task
                 second task
  second project
                 first task
 etc
and so on
how could i cater this like nested foreach and once foreach condition depends on it parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) like so:

In your controller:

```
$companies = Company::with('projects.tasks')->get();
return view('yourview', compact('companies'));
```

In your view

```
@foreach($companies as $company)
    @foreach($company->tasks as $task)
        <p>{{$company->name}} {{$task->name}} </p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```